# Calling a function in one place affects other places that also call that function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple page that has two parts: a label that displays 50% of the time after a page load, and a 'Roll' button that simulates the result of rolling a six sided die.  Both of these parts use a `d6` function that uses Math.Random.

These should be independent parts. Pressing the Roll button should not affect whether 'hello' is displayed or not, but that's what happens.  Pressing the Roll button will often make 'hello' appear and disappear.  Why does this happen, and how can I stop it?

Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/summer-monad-457k9j?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A5%2C1-35%2C2

```
export default function App() {
  const [dieRollResult, setDieRollResult] = useState<number>(0);

  const die = (size: number): number => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + 1;
  };

  const d6 = () => die(6);

  const shouldLabelBeVisible = () => (d6() <= 3 ? "visible" : "hidden");

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Typography visibility={shouldLabelBeVisible}>hello</Typography>
      <Typography>{dieRollResult}</Typography>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setDieRollResult(d6());
        }}
      >
        Roll
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button => setDieRollResult to a different value => trigger a rerender => `const shouldLabelBeVisible = () => (d6() <= 3 ? "visible" : "hidden");` is re-caculated => `shouldLabelBeVisible` get a new value => the text "hello" change it visibility

What you should do here is to make use of useMemo hook with the dependencies is an empty array (to say that run only one time)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const die = (size: number): number => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + 1;
};

const d6 = () => die(6);

export default function App() {
  const [dieRollResult, setDieRollResult] = useState<number>(0);

  const shouldLabelBeVisible = useMemo(() => {
    return d6() <= 3 ? "visible" : "hidden";
  }, []);

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Typography visibility={shouldLabelBeVisible}>hello</Typography>
      <Typography>{dieRollResult}</Typography>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setDieRollResult(d6());
        }}
      >
        Roll
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: So, every time the original `App()` is called, the `const` gets re-evaluated, rather than just once at load time?  (And `useMemo` saves the value so when re-evaluated it returns the same value, right?)

Comment: yes, every free variables (variables that not created by useMemo and useCallback) is re-declared when the component is re-rendered. UseMemo and useCallback make them only re-caculated when the dependencies array change